# Gradle sync failed: Can't load library windows-amd64\native-platform.dll

Tags: android, gradle

Updated from Android Studio 1.4 to 2.0, and had the IDE change my gradle dependency to 2.0 from 1.x in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
}
```

Updated the project gradle version to 2.10.

When I tried to sync a project with the gradle files, or refresh the project, I now get the following error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Can't load library: C:\Users\foobar\.gradle\native\19\windows-amd64\native-platform.dll
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455960/441786

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429504/gradle-exception-failed-to-load-native-library-native-platform-dll/60370611#60370611

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429504/gradle-exception-failed-to-load-native-library-native-platform-dll/60370611#60370611

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the "native" folder from gradle path:

```
.gradle\native\19\windows-amd64\native-platform.dll
```

When run again, it will regenerate the "native" folder, and the associative .dll.

Comment: This worked for me. The issue was that my "_.dll" was missing, and only the "_.dll.lock" was present in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

For me, going in and just deleting the 'native' folder, then allowing Android Studio to resync fixed the issue for me. I believe I had a the same or similar issue as CodyF did; my .dll was missing. The only file in the native\19\windows-amd64 folder was a .dll.lock file.

Comment: When you say "Delete the native folder" you mean really delete the folder from windows or deleting the "native" word from some Environment Variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just rename **native-platform.dll.lock** file to  **native-platform.dll**

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes, Loading of `DLL` from temp directories may be disabled,
you can try creating a `tmp` directory and changing `GRADLE_OPTS` to point to the location which you have created.
for windows

```
open CMD
mkdir $some_location
set GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.native.dir=/$some_location"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything for 2 days.
Then i created c:\gradletemp, made the config to use it and ran Eclipse as Administrator. 
This worked for me!

ps: installed eclipse AND gradle with chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure Gradle user home path is empty